# The central ideas in Hales's proof of the Honeycomb conjecture.

Tags: geometry, discrete-mathematics, proof-explanation, combinatorial-geometry, discrete-geometry

I have been trying to understand Thomas Hales's proof of the honeycomb conjecture: https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9906042.pdf

However, despite the fact that the paper is clearly written, I find myself lost. I am wondering if anybody who knows this proof would be so kind to give a brief ordered list of the central ideas of the proof, so that I am able to understand what is a central idea and what is a technical detail and enable me to follow the proof better.

Thank you very much,

Maithreya

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment.

I started to read the paper. I don’t know whether I’ll finish it, but Hales have already answered your question and it seems that its farther detalization is not simple but technical:

> “To solve the problem, we replace the planar cluster with a cluster on a ﬂat torus. The torus has the advantages of compactness and a vanishing Euler characteristic. This part of the proof is reminiscent of [FT43], which transports the planar cluster to a sphere. The key inequality, called the hexagonal isoperimetric inequality, appears in Theorem 4. It asserts that a certain functional is uniquely minimized
>   by a regular hexagon of area 1. The isoperimetric properties of the functional force the minimizing ﬁgure to be convex. A penalty term prevents the solution from becoming too “round.” The optimality of the hexagonal honeycomb results”.

Even the rigorous formulations of Honeycomb conjecture which he used is very technical, for instance:

> “**Theorem 1-A (Honeycomb conjecture).** Let $\Gamma$ be a locally ﬁnite graph in $\Bbb R^2$,
>   consisting of smooth curves, and such that $\Bbb R^2\setminus\Gamma$ has inﬁnitely many bounded
>   connected components, all of unit area. Let $C$ be the union of these bounded components. Then
>   $$\operatorname{limsup}_{r\mapsto\infty}\frac{\operatorname{perim}(C\cap B(0, r))}
> {\operatorname{area}(C ∩ B(0, r))}\ge\sqrt[4]{12}.$$
>
> Equality is attained for the regular hexagonal tile”.

Comment: Thank you for your response, and you really did point out the paragraph which captured the essential ideas. However, i am looking for something more: I suppose i am looking to understand the "big picture" of how the $N(P)$s, $L(P)$s, $T(P)$s etc all interact with one another. For example, he uses the Euler characteristic in only one place as far as i can tell - to find an equation for the sum of the $N(P)$s. I find this to be mysterious - something is going on which I am not seeing... and these key steps and their justifications are what i am hoping someone can list and provide insight into.

Comment: (But i nevertheless find the fact that he used the Euler characteristic in this combinatorial quite fascinating, as i am sure you do too!) :).

Comment: @MaithreyaSitaraman This look cool, but, unfortunately, after I have read several first pages of the paper I was lost in very techical exposition so I have to give up.

Comment: quite understandable :) - but, if it helps to motivate, this paper was a milestone paper since the conjecture remained open for such a long time before this paper was written. At least, this fact is what motivates me to really try to understand it well :) (other than the fact that the fundamental question is interesting)